# Files and Folders in Localfolder in WindowsSTore Apps / WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm creating a windows store app. Therefor i need to persist a small amount of data from the user.
For this i create some json files which i write to a local folder.

When I create this files and folders below Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder will they be preserved when i update my application to a new version ?

Are there any other concerns on saving local data this way?

Answer (score 2):

> When I create this files and folders below Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder will they be preserved when i update my application to a new version ?

Yes.  There is even infrastructure for managing versioning, based on the [Version property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.version.aspx).

> Are there any other concerns on saving local data this way?

The main concern is that the data's lifetime is tied to the application.  If the data is "important", you may want to use user data instead of application data to store it.  For details, see [App Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553522.aspx).